# Lineheight issue on IE 11 Bootstrap 3 dropdown menu

Tags: html, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap-3, css

I am having a very odd issue that is only affecting IE 11. On all of my drop downs IE 11 seems to double the line height. I have tried to override it but I haven't had any luck. It works fine in FF and Chrome and EVEN IE 10!

Live site here:

http://avanti.websitewelcome.com/~wilkes/

Joomla 3.2
Bootstrap 3.1

Chad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On template.css , change `display: block` to `display: inline-block;`

`.dropdown-menu > li > a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 3px 20px;
    clear: both;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.4285;
    color: #333333;
    white-space: nowrap;
}`